# How to set PostgreSQL table names in Rails with schema information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have to connect my rails app in a legacy Postgre database. It uses schemas so in a SQL its is common to use something like

```
SELECT * FROM "Financial".budget
```

I want to write a Budget model but I don't know how to set the table name in this case. I've tried the following:

- set_table_name 'budget'
- set_table_name '"Financial".budget'

None have worket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, this bug seems to be solved in 2-3-stable. Take a look at [this post](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/4/24/this-week-in-edge-rails)

Answer (score 4):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :schema_search_path => 'Financial,public'
)
```

If you're using Postgres, the above is probably "good enough" for most situations.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue with Oracle adapter. By default ActiveRecord always quotes table names in SQL and therefore if you specify

```
set_table_name "Financial.budget"
```

then generated SQL will be

```
SELECT * FROM "Financial.budget"
```

which will not work.

To solve this issue you need to monkey patch PostgreSQL adapter. Put into your environment.rb or in separate initializer the following code:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter.class_eval do
  # abstract_adapter calls quote_column_name from quote_table_name, so prevent that
  def quote_table_name(name)
    name
  end
end
```

Now you should define in your model class

```
set_table_name "Financial.budget"
```

and generated SQL will be

```
SELECT * FROM Financial.budget
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your logs -- what SQL is Rails generating with your various options?

Answer (score 0):

```
set_table_name "Financial.budget"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps extending the search path with your schema will help you?

```
SET SEARCH_PATH TO "Financial", public;
```

Then you could write your query unqualified without the schema:

```
SELECT * FROM budget;
```

Answer (score 0):

We designed a gem to make ActiveRecord work with PostgreSQL. Here is a small usage example:
http://greyblake.com/blog/2012/09/06/pg-power-activerecord-extension-for-postgresql/